# Bash if statement not working inside bash -c

Tags: linux, bash

I am creating a handy launcher on the desktop in Linux. It is a launcher of type Application, which I believe needs to run code inside `bash -c '<bash code>'`.

When clicked in sequence, this launcher opens the volume applet, then the Bluetooth applet, then it closes both windows. The if-statement works as desired in shell as follows:

```
if [[ $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/blueman-manager") ]] && [[
     $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/mate-volume-control") ]] ;
then wmctrl -c "Sound Preferences" && wmctrl -c "Bluetooth Devices"; 
elif [[ $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/blueman-manager") ]];
then /usr/bin/mate-volume-control;
else /usr/bin/blueman-manager;
fi
```

When I put that code as one line inside the launcher, the third time it executes the `else` statement. The exact command is:

```
bash -c 'if [[ $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/blueman-manager") ]] && [[ $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/mate-volume-control") ]] ; then wmctrl -c "Sound Preferences" && wmctrl -c "Bluetooth Devices"; elif [[ $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/blueman-manager") ]]; then /usr/bin/mate-volume-control; else /usr/bin/blueman-manager; fi'
```

Debugging effort:
I lost rack of everything I tried (e.g. replaced && with &, tried different syntax with square brackets etc). My impression is that the first if-statement never executes the first `then` clause, but it executes the last `else`.

A simple if-then-if clause opening the two apps works fine in the launcher:

```
# This works
bash -c 'if [[ $(ps -aux | grep -v "grep" | grep -l "/usr/bin/blueman-manager") ]];then /usr/bin/mate-volume-control;else /usr/bin/blueman-manager;fi'
```

Comment: Is it because the single quote from the `if` statement terminates the single quote from your command line?

Comment: Good catch, but unfortunately it does not help! I change those quotes in my question

Comment: Please [edit] to show us the _exact_ command you are having trouble with, and any debugging effort you can demonstrate.

Comment: overall `if pgrep -f /usr/bin/blueman-manager >/dev/null; then`...

Comment: The "This works" example only coincidentally happens to work because the unquoted `grep` doesn't contain any whitespace or shell metacharacters. (In case it's not obvious, `'foo 'bar' baz'` is not an example of nested single quotes; you can't nest them. Instead, it is a quoted `foo ` followed by an unquoted `bar` followed by a quoted `baz`.)

Comment: sorry, I replace again the single quotes in the "This works" example. This is driving me crazy

Comment: Is there any reason to not simply write the commands in a script and make it executable, and put the name of the script instead of the `bash -c '... code here ...'`?

Comment: That would indeed be possible, though a one liner would be easier to "maintain", once it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one liner that works on my new machine, where the bluetooth app is called `blueberry` instead of `blueman-manager`.

```
blue=$(ps aux | grep "blueberry\$"); mate=$(pgrep -f ^mate-volume-control\$); if [ -n "$blue" ] && [ -n "$mate" ]; then wmctrl -c "Sound Preferences" && wmctrl -c "Bluetooth"; elif [ -z "$blue" ]; then blueberry & else mate-volume-control & fi;
```

Compared to the code in my question, I realized that for some reason that bringing the `ps aux | grep` inside the bash tests `[]` does not work.

I also noticed that `fgrep -f` is not working as I expect since it does not do an exact match. For example, when blueberry is not on,  I expect no output from the `pgrep` expression below

```
> ps aux | grep blueberry
2729  0.0  0.2 317220 37220 ?        Sl   09:01   0:00 blueberry-obex-agent
2971  0.1  0.2 542728 46032 ?        Sl   09:01   0:09 blueberry-tray
3200  0.0  0.0   2616   528 ?        S    09:01   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/blueberry/safechild /usr/sbin/rfkill event
25913  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    10:39   0:00 [blueberry] <defunct>

> pgrep -fx '^blueberry$'
25913  #this is [blueberry] <defunct>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, with additional debugging info:

```
blue=$(pgrep -f ^/usr/bin/blueman-manager\$);
mate=$(pgrep -f ^/usr/bin/mate-volume-control\$);
echo "blueman-manager pid=[$blue], mate-volume-control pid=[$mate].";
if test -n "$blue" && test -n "$mate"; then
   wmctrl -c "Sound Preferences" && wmctrl -c "Bluetooth Devices";
elif test -z "$blue" then
   /usr/bin/blueman-manager;
else
   /usr/bin/mate-volume-control;
fi;
```

Comment: It is not the same. I want to close both windows if both windows are open. if not: check if blueman is open. if not, open it, otherwise open the volume. I can make it work on shell, not inside `bash -c '<code>'`

Comment: @aless80 Answer updated. And it should work if converted to one-liner.